# How can I drive a US purchased and financed car in Canada for 2 years?

Tags: canada, car

I am moving from US to Canada.  I hold a Canadian work permit and will work in Ontario for 2 years.

I've recently financed a car in the US and I'd like to bring it to Canada.

I'm aware of the fact that my vehicle is exempted from RIV registration, because I meet the "[Temporary Importation](http://www.riv.ca/RIVExemptions.aspx)" conditions.

My questions are:

As my car is financed, does it still meet this exemption condition?

Should I get any authorization from the lender and provide in Canada?

Am I allowed to get car insurance in Canada for my car?

Is it necessary to register this car in Canada while financed in US?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a principle of Westminster constitutions that whatever is not prohibited by law is permitted and the common law of the Anglosphere has long held that any ambiguity is resolved in favour of the person who did not set the rules.

Given that, assuming your work permit is for a period of 36 months or less, you qualify.   Also, there's no statement on the riv site that hints about the financing state of your car so the fact that you're still making payments on it doesn't affect things.  It *might* matter to your financier, though, so you would probably want to square things with them.

http://www.riv.ca/VehicleAdmissibility.aspx

You only tangentially mention what province.  You will quickly learn that matters.  :)

Automobile insurance and registration is a provincial matter.

You are not only allowed, you are required to have valid insurance.

https://www.ontario.ca/page/register-and-insure-vehicle-ontario

You also need to get an Ontario driver's licence within 60 days.

https://www.thinkinsure.ca/insurance-help-centre/top-15-ontario-drivers-licence-questions.html

Here is another web page you need to consult:

https://www.ontario.ca/faq/what-do-i-need-register-out-province-vehicle-ontario